# How do you set the message box results to go to a tabpage you created in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, tabs

I want to ask the user to for some input to determine the next step to go to in my program. The code looks like this.

```
If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Program More Devices?", "             MORE DEVICES TO PROGRAM", _
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) _
      = DialogResult.No Then
            Application.Exit()
        Else
            <If answer is Yes then I would like to go to Tabpage1>

        End If
```

In the event the user selects the Yes button, I would like the program to go to `tabpage1`
 where
`Me.TabPage1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage`

Comment: Try: `TabControlName.SelectedTab = TabPage1`. Replace 'TabControlName' with your TabControl's Name.

Comment: @BanForFun both of these work, `TabControl1.SelectTab(0)`  or 
            `TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but you could also create a form, that does the same thing if you wanted something custom.

```
Dim dResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to go to tabpage1?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
If dResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
   TabControlName.SelectedTab = TabPage1
ElseIf dResult = DialogResult.No Then
            'do nothing?
End If
```